# Merging and displaying table data based on values

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

I am trying to make a table that displays rows but if there are ones that have the same model_number and year_introduced then merge them but add the location from the second row to the first

So I have a table that looks like this right now

```
archive_id    model_number    year_introduced    location
1001          B12             2012               SKID 43
1002          B12             2012               SKID 47
1003          B12             2012               SKID 41
1004          B12             2012               SKID 56
```

but I want it to look like this

```
archive_id    model_number    year_introduced    location
1001          B12             2012               SKID 43, SKID 47, SKID 41, SKID 56
```

I am displaying the data using C# and ASP.NET so would I adjust the query to merge the lines or would I use C# to merge them in the DataTable that I have

here is how I am displaying the data (it doesnt include all of the data because the more info button will bring them to a page that includes it all)

```
foreach (DataRow dataRow in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
{
    yearHead.InnerText = decade.ToString() + "'s";
    TableRow row = new TableRow();
    row.ID = "rows" + x;
    row.Attributes.Add("class", "tblRow");

    TableCell cell = new TableCell();
    cell.Attributes.Add("class", "cell");
    cell.ID = "product_name" + x;
    cell.Text = dataRow["PRODUCT_NAME"].ToString();
    row.Cells.Add(cell);

    cell = new TableCell();
    cell.ID = "model_number" + x;
    cell.Text = dataRow["MODEL_NUMBER"].ToString();
    row.Cells.Add(cell);

    cell = new TableCell();
    cell.ID = "years" + x;
    if (dataRow["YEAR_INTRODUCED"] != null)
    {
        cell.Text = dataRow["YEAR_INTRODUCED"].ToString();
        row.Cells.Add(cell);
    }
    else
    {
        cell.Text = "Unknown Start Date";
        row.Cells.Add(cell);
    }

    cell = new TableCell();
    cell.ID = "more_info" + x;

    Button moreInfo = new Button();
    moreInfo.Attributes.Add("runat", "server");
    moreInfo.UseSubmitBehavior = false;
    moreInfo.CommandName = "moreInfoClicked";
    moreInfo.Text = "Details";
    moreInfo.ID = "info_" + dataRow["ARCHIVE_ID_NUMBER"].ToString();
    moreInfo.CommandName = x.ToString();
    moreInfo.CommandArgument = dataRow["ARCHIVE_ID_NUMBER"].ToString();
    moreInfo.ControlStyle.CssClass = "moreInfoButton";

    cell.Controls.Add(moreInfo);
    row.Cells.Add(cell);

    product.Rows.Add(row);
    x += 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to convert the column values int list on SQL server side and then bind resulting rowset (datatable) to a `GridView` or `ListView`.

```
select distinct model_number, year_introduced
,stuff((select ', '+location as [text()]  
       from tbl t1 
          where t1.year_introduced = t.year_introduced 
            and t1.model_number = t.model_number for xml  path('')),1,1,'') lst
from tbl t
```

Note that `archive_id` cannot be included here because each value produce different `location`. You can apply similar trick to `archive_id` column or combine `archive_id` with `location`.

```
select ', ' + cast(archive_id as varchar) + ': ' + location as [text()]...
```

Answer (score 0):

This will have archieve_id as you specified in the question and also the data will be combined by comma in location column

```
SELECT  min([archive_id]) as archive_id,[model_number],[year_introduced],
     STUFF((
             SELECT ', '  + CAST([location] AS VARCHAR(MAX)) 
                   FROM 
             [Test]
                   WHERE 
             ([model_number] = Results.[model_number] and [year_introduced]=                                                             Results.[year_introduced]) 
             FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE).value('(./text())[1]','VARCHAR(MAX)')
             ,1,2,'') AS Location
                   FROM 
             [Test] Results
                    GROUP BY 
             [model_number],[year_introduced]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are on SQL Server 2017, you can do it :

```
SELECT model_number, year_introduced, 
STRING_AGG (location , ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY archive_id) AS locations 
FROM Yourtable
GROUP BY model_number, year_introduced
```

Otherwise, use

```
SELECT t0.model_number, t0.year_introduced
     , STUFF((
       SELECT ',' + t1.location
         FROM yourtable t1
        WHERE t0.model_number=t1.model_number and t0.year_introduced=t1.year_introduced
        ORDER BY t1.archive_id
          FOR XML PATH('')), 1, LEN(','), '') AS Locations
  FROM yourtable t0
 GROUP BY t0.model_number, t0.year_introduced
```

Answer (score -1):

It would be most efficient to use C# to merge the results in my opinion.

Comment: the archive_id is the primary key so each one only has one location on it

Comment: right now my query looks like this cmd = @"Select * From ARCHIVE_DECADE_TBL WHERE DECADE_" + decade + @"=@decade AND PRODUCT_LINE=@Line AND QUANTITY is not null AND QUANTITY <> 0 ORDER BY PRODUCT_NAME;"; so by adjusting it i mean should I add a group by or any other term to group the ones that have the same year and model number

Comment: Ok I understand now. I edited my answer. It would be most efficient for you to simply select everything from your Table and merge the results in C#. If I'm not mistaken the group by still does not return you the results on the same row.

Comment: Ok do you know the most efficient way to do that? should I clone the table I have and if the data matches then combine them? If so how would I combine them but append the location data instead of replacing it?

Comment: That is what I was thinking you should do. So:

Get Table from the database.
Loop through the Table.
If data matches (in this case model_number and year_introduced), add the text in the location column to a variable (let's say X).
When you're done looping through the table, variable X should have all the locations in it for that data (model_number and year_introduced).